# Including boost libraries in make files via env file

Tags: boost, makefile

I have a question regarding the inclusion of boost libraries to make files. This question has been asked (and answered) multiple times in this forum and others, I could not solve my problem however using suggestions from there, since I am stuck in a much more basic stage.

I am using a ready made make file that includes the address of the boost libraries via an env file that is included in the beginning of the makefile. Thus, all I have to do is provide the correct folder of the boost libraries, however I seem to be providing the wrong address, as I get an error that the boost libraries could not be found:.

```
Demo_00.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `boost::mpi::environment::environment(int&, char**&, bool)'
Demo_00.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `boost::mpi::communicator::communicator()'
Demo_00.cpp:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `boost::mpi::communicator::rank() const'
Demo_00.cpp:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `boost::mpi::communicator::rank() const'
Demo_00.cpp:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `boost::mpi::environment::~environment()'
Demo_00.cpp:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `boost::mpi::environment::~environment()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The specific part of the env file looks like this:

```
BOOST_INCLUDE=-I./home/user/Documents/RHPC_2.0/INSTALLATION/boost_1_54_0/
BOOST_LIB_DIR=-L./home/user/Documents/RHPC_2.0/INSTALLATION/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib
BOOST_LIBS=-lboost_mpi-xgcc42-mt -lboost_serialization-xgcc42-mt -lboost_system-xgcc42-mt -lboost_filesystem-xgcc42-mt
```

My questions:

In the template file of the env file, the first address ended with '.../boost_1_54_0/include', my boost folder does not have an include folder however (there are some further within the folder only). Is this a problem?

Do I need to make any adjustment to BOOST_LIBS?

Is there maybe a simple way of identifying the correct addresses using cmake? I worked my way through the cmake documentary but did not quite get how this would be implemented.

Also: I have just tried to 'compile+link' by hand, which only worked for the compiling part but not for linking. Here is the compiling:

```
/home/user/Documents/RHPC_2.0/INSTALLATION/mpich2-1.4.1p1/bin/mpicxx -c -I/home/user/Documents/RHPC_2.0/INSTALLATION/boost_1_54_0/ -o Demo_00.o Demo_00.cpp
```

Here is the Linking part, which did not work

```
    /home/user/Documents/RHPC_2.0/INSTALLATION/mpich2-1.4.1p1/bin/mpicxx -L/home/user/Documents/RHPC_2.0/INSTALLATION/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib/ Demo_00.cpp -lboost_mpi-xgcc42-mt -lboost_serialization-xgcc42-mt -lboost_system-xgcc42-mt -lboost_filesystem-xgcc42-mt
```

After this command I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_mpi-xgcc42-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_serialization-xgcc42-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system-xgcc42-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem-xgcc42-mt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems, here the problem lies with the these last 4 files and not the entire boost folders. The above folders /usr/bin/ld are also not existent to my knowledge.

I appreciate your help and again my apologies for bringing up this topic yet again.

Thanks,
Tartaglia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever is passed to `-I` should be pointing to the folder having `boost/*hpp` files under it (say `boost/shared_ptr.hpp`).

Whatever is passed to `-L` should be the folder where all of those passed to `-l` reside (when you say `-lthename` the respective file name is `libthename.so`).

Also these BOOST_* environment variables should be concatenated to the compiler/linker command line (I assume that is already happening automatically in your case).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So I located the *.hpp and they are indeed in the .../boost/ folder. So the first line would be:

BOOST_INCLUDE=-I./home/user/Documents/RHPC_2.0/INSTALLATION/boost_1_54_0/boost 

From looking at the folders it seems that the corresponding *.cpp files for the above are under .../libs, so the second line should be:

BOOST_LIB_DIR=-L./home/user/Documents/RHPC_2.0/INSTALLATION/boost_1_54_0`/lib

I am still getting the same error message however. Can I use any of these folders for the linking by hand approach above?

Comment: @user3398324 - the `boost` part should **not** be included in the path, it should be referred in the source code as `#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>`. Have you compiled and installed boost or just downloaded the source code?

Comment: I see, the source code of my file actually did include the hpp file:

#include <boost/mpi.hpp>

So the first line should be: 

 BOOST_INCLUDE=-I/home/user/Documents/RHPC_2.0/INSTALLATION/boost_1_54_0/

I installed Boost using a sh file, but I am not sure whether the files were actually compiled, this is what the part of the sh. file looked like:

Comment: tar -xvf boost_1_54_0.tar.gz

  mkdir -p $BASE_DIR/Boost/Boost_1.54/include

  cp -r ./boost_1_54_0/boost $BASE_DIR/Boost/Boost_1.54/include

  cd boost_1_54_0

  ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=$BASE_DIR/Boost/Boost_1.54/ --with-libraries=system,filesystem,mpi,serialization

  echo "using mpi : $MPI_COMPILER_INVOCATION ;" >>./tools/build/v2/user-config.jam

  ./b2 --layout=tagged link=static variant=release threading=multi runtime-link=static stage install

Comment: Sorry about the format, I cannot add any new answers, and formatting options are very limited in the comments. 

Is there a way to check whether I actually compiled the boost source code (I did run a simple hello world type of file from the boost tutorial, which worked).

Comment: So I just found a typo in the address where the boost libraries are located, let me try to correct this quick, I will report back asap.

Comment: So apart from the typo (never gets old), something else caught my attention: the files listed under BOOST_LIBS are named slightly differently in my folder, i.e.:

libboost_wserialization-mt-s
libboost_system-mt-s
libboost_serialization-mt-s
libboost_mpi-mt-s
libboost_filesystem-mt-s

In the documentation I am using, it says to ignore the different endings and the libboost instead of lboost, but what about the other differences in the names?

Comment: So at this point I modified some of the other paths in the env file and this did not affect my abiliy to use make. So I am wondering how do I connect the make command I am using in the terminal with the makefile? It seems the whole time I was using a different make file but I am not sure how to control which makefile is used.

Comment: So I moved my main.cpp file to the folder where the env file and the makefile are located, and now there seems to be some interaction, I am still getting some error messages, I'll try to figure this out.

Comment: So now I can get a simple HelloWorld.cpp file to work with make, however once I include MPI commands these seem to to cause errors (these are also included via the env. file), I will start a new question since this is not related to the boost libraries at all.